# Node.js shared memory and atomics documentation and how tos

Tags: javascript, node.js

It appears shared memory and atomics was added in Node 9.0.0: http://node.green/#ES2017-features-shared-memory-and-atomics-Atomics-add

I'm trying to find the official documentation but can't seem to locate it at: https://nodejs.org/api/index.html

Anyone know where it might be located?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EVOLVING ANSWER**

It appears that Node 9.0.0 supports `SharedArrayBuffer` which can be found on MDN at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/SharedArrayBuffer

and `atomics`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Atomics/store

This was added to Node.js in v9.0.0: http://node.green/#ES2017-features-shared-memory-and-atomics-SharedArrayBuffer

I will continue to document everything I learn on this for others who are interested in utilizing this in Node.js.

**YouTube Videos**
*Nidin Vinayakan: Shared Memory & Parallel Programming with JavaScript | JSConf EU 2017*
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vvqfmskTIjE

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find a Node.js + AssemblyScript multithreading boilerplate code.

#### Repo : [as-multithreading-boilerplate](https://github.com/01alchemist/as-multithreading-boilerplate)

## Dependencies

- `Node.js@10.5.0`
- `AssemblyScript@0.6.0`

## This repo shows

1. Basic setup to do multithreading using nodejs `worker_threads`
2. Basic `WebAssembly` multithreading with `AssemblyScript`
3. Atomic `WebAssembly` memory allocator